# How to use md5sum for checksum with an md5 file which doesn't contain the filename

Tags: hashsum

I have 2 files test.txt and test.txt.md5. I would like to verify the checksum of test.txt.

The gnu tool md5sum requires an md5 file with the following format "[md5-hash][space][space][filename]" (md5sum -c test.txt.md5). Unfortunately my test.txt.md5 only contains the md5 hash (without the spaces and filename).

How can I pass the hash from the "test.txt.md5" file to the "md5sum -c" command? I guess I have to use the standard input however all examples I have seen try to recreate the md5sum file format

The content of the files is:

`test.txt`:

```
test
```

and `test.txt.md5`:

```
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249
```

Comment: `cmp test.txt.md5 <(md5sum test.txt | awk '{print $1}')  && echo $?`  If the result returned is `0` then there is a match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many commands, `md5sum` has the ability to read from the standard input if an option's value is `-` (from `man md5sum`):

> Print or check MD5 (128-bit) checksums.  With no FILE, or **when FILE is -, read standard input**.

Since you know the file name, you could simply print the contents of your md5 file, a couple of spaces and then the name and pass that to `md5sum`:

```
$ cat test.txt.md5 
5a6d311c0d8f6d1dd03c1c129061d3b1
$ md5sum -c <(printf "%s  test.txt\n" $(cat test.txt.md5)) 
test.txt: OK
```

Another option would be to add the file name to your file:

```
$ sed -i  's/$/  test.txt/' test.txt.md5
$ md5sum -c test.txt.md5 
test.txt: OK
```

Answer (score 2):

You can re-calculate the MD5 checksum of your file and compare it to that stored in `test.txt.md5`:

```
cmp test.txt.md5 <(md5sum test.txt | cut -d\  -f1)
```

If there's no output then the checksums match.

Comment: I got a error when I ran you suggested command (`Missing name for redirect`). However a minor change made it work (`md5sum test.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | cmp test.txt.md5 -`). Thanks for the cmp hint though! :)